# Are these two private subnets completely isolated from each other?

Tags: subnet, ip-address, networking

Im trying to set up a subnet address range in my local network but the private address ranges of

```
172.16.1.1
192.168.1.1
10.1.10.1
```

are all already being used.

So I was wondering, 
if I make this subnet 172.17.1.1, will it be totally isolated from 172.16.1.1? and can I use both subnets without any problems? 
The subnet Im making now will also be a vlan.

Im just worried because I think I read somewhere that the first part of the ip address ranges cannot be the same.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The octets mean nothing. You cannot tell if they overlap without knowing the mask length of each. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on the subnet mask of the 172.16.1.0 network.  If it is a /16 or longer, then 172.17.1 will fall outside the range and be fine to use

Comment: so their subnet masks cant be the same?

Comment: @user59250 Their masks can be the same as long as they're /16 (255.255.0.0) or longer (like /24 255.255.255.0). If they're shorter than /16, they will overlap and will not be segregated.